# Similar Class like String to create object as same as creating String literal object

Tags: java, string

Few days back I faced a very interesting question below:

Make a Class like String in java so that you can create object like the same way, we can create object using String literal. The question is not about the immutability, We all know those theories.

example:

### For String

There are two ways of creating object of String class i.e.

```
1. String s1 = new String("ABC");
2. String s2 = "XYZ";
```

The question is regarding the 2nd case. Need to create a custom Class so that we can create object, the same way as the above 2nd case.

i.e.

let say the Class name is Test.class

```
class Test {
   private int a; // or array of characters like String class
   Test(int a) {
     this.a = a;
   }
}
```

I want to have some thing like below:

```
Test t = 10;
```

and the object gets instantiated.

Thanks
Sandip

Answer (score 0):

String theory is different than other Objects. As we all know to represent a object it's reference is necessary, which resides in stack. Means for a simple object only **Stack** and **Heap** are enough.

But in String case there is one more concept of **String Literal Pool**. So you can't implement it explicitly.